# Ассемблер x86 в OpenCL

Tags: ассемблер, opencl

Возможно ли при написании кернела использовать ассемблерные вставки вроде?

```
asm{
 mov  eax,123
 shl  eax,1
}
```

Comment: А кто запрешает? :)

Comment: Ну так поделитесь опытом, каким образом можно написать кернел на ассемблере?